# VB.NET navigate to a specific ListBox item

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selecteditem

I have a listbox that I load items into. Each line starts with time in HH:mm:ss format. I want a button such that on the click of it, the listbox selected item would navigate to a line that starts with a particular time, as entered into a textbox by the user. Secondly, I have a textbox that copies the first 5 characters of the selecteditem, using **selecteditem.text.tostring.substring(0,5)**.  Now, I need to capture the first 5 characters of the line RIGHT BELOW the selected item. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ListBox's `FindString()` method you can find the index of the first item starting with the specified string. You can then use that to set the `SelectedIndex` property which will select the item at the specified index.

To get the item below the currenty selected one you just have to get `SelectedIndex + 1` from the `Items` collection.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim Index As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text) 'Find the index of the item starting with whatever is in TextBox1.
    If Index > -1 Then 'Check if the item exists/was found.
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Index
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.Items(Index).ToString().Substring(0, 5)

        If Index < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then 'Check if the found item is the last item or not.
            TextBox3.Text = ListBox1.Items(Index + 1).ToString().SubString(0, 5)
        Else 'This was the last item.
            MessageBox.Show("You've reached the end of the list.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If

    Else 'No item was found.
        MessageBox.Show("No item found starting with the specified text!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Visual Vincent and @IFON26 too. I have not implemented the code but reading it, I have strong hope that it will work.

Comment: @MordC : I actually haven't tested it myself as I have no access to a computer at the moment, but the coding is so basic that there should not be any problems with it.

Comment: I tried the code today but it didn't work PERFECTLY. I am however grateful because your answer gave me some clues on solving some related problems. The part that DID NOT WORK is navigating to a line I the listbox that contains characters as entered by user into a textbox. I would be glad if you could implement and see. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @MordC : Okay...? I will take a look at it.

Comment: @MordC : I don't understand, it works perfectly for me. Do you get any errors? I did a quick test, see my screenshots: http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ListBoxNavigationTest.png _(I tried it only with letters too, works as perfect)._

Comment: So unless there's something strange going on, I'd say you've done something wrong with the code :)

Comment: It worked and what I needed in addition was provided according to this Microsoft. MSDN l[Navigation Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5et1818(v=vs.110).aspx) . The Setselected property was used. Thank ps much.

Comment: @MordC : But, doing `SetSelected()` or `SelectedIndex = ...` does the same thing :). I just copy-pasted my code when testing and it worked completely. Anyway, glad you got it working!

Comment: My file is a circular one and that may explain why I used to have the problem. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 2
```

0 equal first line
1  equal second line
2 equal third line 
and finish like that

or you can add -1 in the end like this below

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 - 1
```

so you can select the actual line number two

Comment: This does not select anything, it just gets the first item.

Comment: i told him 0 equal  the item  he wants to select -_-

Comment: This still doesn't actually select anything, just gets the item at index 0. Nor does it help him much with his question. I know you cannot comment yet, but this should otherwise have been one. It's correct what you say, but an answer should be more thorough.

Comment: works for me, i dont know who is the master of vb here, try put 1 instead of 0 
you will see

Comment: _Yes it works_, I didn't say that it wouldn't. But it doesn't _physically select_ the item. Which is what he wanted if I understood his question right. Either way the answer is still not very thorough, and doesn't help him much with his question. Your code _gets_ the item, it doesn't _select_ it.

Comment: Mmm, it's better. :)

Comment: I think it's good that you pointed out that one can take the item you want - 1 to get the index. It makes it easier to remember.